# Can I use a WooCommerce function without any WooCommerce page?

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, price

I've WooCommerce installed on my WordPress site. After this, I've created a custom page template that has nothing to do with WooCommerce. Within this template, I want to use the WooCommerce `wc_price()` function but it doesn't work. This is what I've tried:

```
global $woocommerce;
$woocommerce->wc_price(12);
--
WC()->wc_price(12);
```

But both of this don't works. So how can I use this function within my custom template (if possible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the function without WC object. Below is the definition of that function. So you can simply use like `wc_price(12)`

```
function wc_price( $price, $args = array() ) {
    $args = apply_filters(
        'wc_price_args', wp_parse_args(
            $args, array(
                'ex_tax_label'       => false,
                'currency'           => '',
                'decimal_separator'  => wc_get_price_decimal_separator(),
                'thousand_separator' => wc_get_price_thousand_separator(),
                'decimals'           => wc_get_price_decimals(),
                'price_format'       => get_woocommerce_price_format(),
            )
        )
    );

    $unformatted_price = $price;
    $negative          = $price < 0;
    $price             = apply_filters( 'raw_woocommerce_price', floatval( $negative ? $price * -1 : $price ) );
    $price             = apply_filters( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', number_format( $price, $args['decimals'], $args['decimal_separator'], $args['thousand_separator'] ), $price, $args['decimals'], $args['decimal_separator'], $args['thousand_separator'] );

    if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', false ) && $args['decimals'] > 0 ) {
        $price = wc_trim_zeros( $price );
    }

    $formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $args['price_format'], '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $args['currency'] ) . '</span>', $price );
    $return          = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price . '</span>';

    if ( $args['ex_tax_label'] && wc_tax_enabled() ) {
        $return .= ' <small class="woocommerce-Price-taxLabel tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
    }


    return apply_filters( 'wc_price', $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get product price ,you can use this  code:

```
global $product;
$product->get_price());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-load.php' );
```

Just write this in any of your template and then you can access woocommerce content like products, orders. I have tried it and well worked..